# Magento 2 composer update removes pub/media and all other important folders

Tags: upgrade, composer

After running composer update, composer starts upgrading and downloading.

After that the update of packages are marked red "Update of name/module_name failed".

And **all my important folders and files (bin,vendor, ..) are empty or gone**.

Does anybody know what can have caused this unwanted behaviour? I managed to recover the files from backup, but it took me quite some time.

[image]

Comment: Remove vendor and try composer install it will work fine don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Some cases can be caused this unwanted behaviour: when you run `composer update` which includes updating magento version or you remove one of the following folders: `vendor`, `vendor/magento/magento2-base` (for the Open source version), `magento/magento2-ee-base` (for the Enterprise version).

You can resolve this issue by clear compose cache and run composer update again:

```
composer clear-cache
composer update
```

Comment: Thanks! I downgraded and upgraded composer and ran in some other odd problems. But it works again!